# Trigonometric limit with l'Hospital

Tags: calculus

I tried doing the limit by differentiating both the numerator and denominator but it is still 0/0 form, if I continue differentiating I still get 0/0 can someone give a hint or maybe show me if I've done any mistake, please try to be clear for any help

[image]

Comment: Did you try L'Hopital a second time?  Maybe third time is the charm....

Comment: yes but it is very long and it's still 0/0, can you try and tell me if I've made any mistake during differetiation

Comment: @Admid Kullolli, the third time you won't get 0.

Comment: ok thanks i'll try

Comment: by the way what was the limit after the second time?

Answer (score 1):

On differentiation we get $$\frac{\sec^24x-\sec^2x}{\cos4x-\cos x}$$

which is $$-\dfrac{\cos^24x-\cos^2x}{\cos4x-\cos x}\cdot\frac1{\cos^24x\cos^2x}$$

As $x\to0^+,\cos4x-\cos x\to0\implies\cos4x-\cos x\ne0$, so can be cancelled out safely

Comment: yet not very clear

Comment: @AdmirKullolli, Please pinpoint the line of confusion

Comment: I don't think that's the derivative of the numerator

Comment: sorry i got it now but why the derivative is the expression below @lab bhattacharje

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f(x)=\tan x$ can be written $f'(x)=1/\cos^2x$, so the first application of l’Hôpital gives
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{12}{\cos^{2}4x}-\dfrac{12}{\cos^2x}}{12\cos4x-12\cos x}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\cos^{2}4x}-\dfrac{1}{\cos^2x}}{\cos4x-\cos x}
$$
which doesn't seem so promising, even after removing the factors $12$. However, a good rule to keep in mind is “try algebraic simplifications before going on with l’Hôpital”. The numerator can be written as
$$
\frac{\cos^2x-\cos^24x}{\cos^24x\cos^2x}=
\frac{(\cos x-\cos4x)(\cos x+\cos 4x)}{\cos^24x\cos^2x}
$$
so the limit becomes, after canceling the common factor $\cos x-\cos4x$ (you can do it, because it's non zero in a neighborhood of $0$, except at $0$),
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\cos x-\cos4x)(\cos x+\cos 4x)}{\cos^24x\cos^2x}
\frac{1}{\cos4x-\cos x}
=
\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{\cos x+\cos 4x}{\cos^24x\cos^2x}=-2
$$